# Webpack works but webpack-dev-server fails

Tags: webpack

I am using webpack to package some front-end code. When I packaged with webpack, everything works fine, but when I use webpack-dev-server to publish to the local server, I get some errors.

This is the result of executing webpack.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I34mz.png)

This is the result of excuting webpack-dev-server.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7uUY.png)

The configuration of the webpack.config.js is as follows:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

// 
var WEBPACK_ENV = process.env.WEBPACK_ENV || 'dev';

// 获取html-webpack-plugin参数的方法
var getHtmlConfig = function(name){
    return {
        template: './src/view/' + name + '.html',
        filename: 'view/' + name + '.html',
        inject: true,
        hash: true,
        chunks: ['common', name]
    }
};

// webpack config
var config = {
    // mode: 'dev' === WEBPACK_ENV ? 'development' : 'production',
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        'common' : ['./src/page/common/index.js'],
        'index' : ['./src/page/index/index.js'],
        'login' : ['./src/page/login/index.js'],
    },
    devServer: {
        contentBase: './dist/view'
    },
    output: {
        // path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/dist/',
        filename: 'js/[name].js'
    },
    externals: {
        'jquery' : 'window.jQuery'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            // css文件的处理
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                     MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    'css-loader'
                ]
            },
            // 图片的配置
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                  {
                    loader: 'url-loader',
                    options: {
                      limit: 2048,
                      name: 'resource/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                  }
                ]
            },
            // 字体图标的配置
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'url-loader',
                        options: {
                            limit: 8192,
                            name: 'resource/[name].[ext]'
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            util : path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/util'),
            page : path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/page'),
            service : path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/service'),
            image : path.resolve(__dirname + '/src/image'),
        }
    },
    optimization: {
        runtimeChunk: false,
        splitChunks: {
            cacheGroups: {
                common: {
                    name: "common",
                    chunks: "all",
                    minChunks: 2
                }
            }
        }
    },
    plugins: [
        // new CleanWebpackPlugin(['dist']),
        // 把CSS单独打包到文件里
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: "css/[name].css",
        }),
        // HTML模版的处理
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(getHtmlConfig('index')),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin(getHtmlConfig('login')),
    ],

    devServer: {
        port: 8088,
        inline: true,
        proxy: {
            '**/*.do' : {
                target: 'http://localhost:8088/',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
};

/*if('dev' === WEBPACK_ENV){
    config.entry.common.push('webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8088/');
}*/

module.exports = config;
```

the version of webpack is 4.29.5 
the version of webpack-cli is 3.2.3 
the version of webpack-dev-server is 3.2.1

I don't know why this is happening. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had similar problem and found solution here: [github issues](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin/issues/257)

Documentation says:
"Best avoid using an entrypoint as name for a cacheGroup", so basically you should change

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            common: {
                name: "common",
                chunks: "all",
                minChunks: 2
            }
        }
    }
},
```

to:

```
optimization: {
    runtimeChunk: false,
    splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
            commonStyle: { // changed this name of group
                name: "common", // to be different from word used here
                chunks: "all",
                minChunks: 2
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This method works. However, another problem has arisen, and the hot deployment has failed. But in general, thank you for your answer.